# jQuery prependTo selector string

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

So, I'm at a stage where I have the script choosing the right body of a HTML webpage, but instead of selecting the correct sub-elements, the script adds an image to every single possible element instead.

I'm having trouble at getting the selector to work the way I want it to, and I could use a little advice.

(Code by username "Twisty", slightly altered)

```
$("a").each(function(i, el){
  var $a = $(el);
  if($a.attr("href").indexOf(".pdf")){
    var $icon = $("<img>", {
      src: "img/pdf.png",
      alt: "PDF"
    }).prependTo($a).position({
      my: "right+5 top",
      at: "left top",
      of: $a
    });
  }
});
```

This code finds the image and slaps it onto the correct HTML elements, but the prependTo selector is too undefined.

I tried a lot of possible solutions like using find(".pdf") and so on, but I'm constantly doing something wrong.

Example of an attempt to copy already discovered solutions:

```
$("a").each(function(i, el){
    var $a = $(el);
    if(String($a.attr("href").indexOf(".pdf")))
    $(el).children($a).prependTo($(".pdf", el));
});
```

And what I'm trying to do is to make the selector add an image that has been selected to a link with ".pdf" in it

Example element with .pdf in it:

```
<a href="http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf">ECMAScript Language Specification (an external PDF)</a>
```

Comment: Can you please give us some sample html you are working with

Comment: `if($a.attr("href").indexOf(".pdf"))` will always be true, unless the `href` attribute has only `".pdf"` as its content

Comment: Added an example element with a link that has pdf in it (This should get a picture added to it. A link with no picture would otherwise be similar but it would not have ".pdf" on the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`String.prototype.indexOf(searchValue[, fromIndex])`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) returns the index where the passed `searchValue` has been found. If the `searchValue` cannot be found it returns `-1`.

And because `-1` is a [truthy value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) which evaluates as `true` in an comparison like:

```
if($a.attr("href").indexOf(".pdf")){
  //...
}
```

your `if(...)` will only be skipped, when the `href` attribute has `".pdf"` as its content because then `.indexOf(".pdf")` would return `0` which is a [falsy value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) which evaluates to `false`.

You have to explicitly test for this "found" case:

```
if($a.attr("href").indexOf(".pdf") > -1){
  //...
}
```

Comment: This works! Thanks for the explanation as well, now I understand a little bit better as to where I was doing wrong things

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to read http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/

```
$('a[href$=".pdf"]').each(function(){
    $(this).prepend('<img src="img/pdf.png" alt="PDF" />');

    $('>img:first',this).position({
      my: "right+5 top",
      at: "left top",
      of: // CAN BE $(this) or $(this)[0], or just remove position
    });
});
```